# Ordered products report exclude orders with status closed

Tags: magento2, reports

the default Magento2 report from ordered products excludes orders with status canceled. I also want to exclude status closed.

```
/app/code/Magento/Reports/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Sold/Collection.php
```

in line 60 shows

```
  $connection->quoteInto("{$orderTableAliasName}.state <> ?", \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED),
```

How can I add STATE_CLOSED here? I tried a bit but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your condition should be in your case

```php
$connection->quoteInto(
    "{$orderTableAliasName}.state NOT IN (?)", 
    [
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED, 
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CLOSED
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, its working!

Comment: you are most welcome! :)